# LINQ Expression not evaluating correctly

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following LINQ expression that's not returning the appropriate response

```
    var query = from quote in db.Quotes
                where quote.QuoteStatus == "Estimating" || quote.QuoteStatus == "Rejected"
                from emp in db.Employees
                where emp.EmployeeID == quote.EmployeeID
                orderby quote.QuoteID descending
                select new 
                { 
                    quote.QuoteID, 
                    quote.DateDue, 
                    Company = quote.Company.CompanyName, 
                    Attachments = quote.Attachments.Count, 
                    Employee = emp.FullName, 
                    Estimator =  (quote.EstimatorID != null && quote.EstimatorID != String.Empty) 
                    ? db.Employees.Single (c => c.EmployeeID == quote.EstimatorID).FullName 
                    : "Unassigned", 
                    Status = quote.QuoteStatus, Priority = quote.Priority 
                };
```

The problem lies in the `Estimator = (quote.EstimatorID != null && quote.EstimatorID != String.Empty) ? db.Employees.Single(c => c.EmployeeID == quote.EstimatorID).FullName : "Unassigned"` part.

I NEVER get it to evalueate to "Unassigned", on the ones that are supposed to, it just returns `null`. Have I written this wrong?

Comment: There is a function: `string.IsNullOrEmpty` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx

Comment: Does quote.Estimator ever evaluate to `null` or `String.Empty`?

Comment: yes it does, occasionally. This is an old DB that I've inherited.

Comment: +1 Robert: I wondered the same thing. It may be inadvertently returning an untrimmed string.

Comment: Nevertheless, I would check and make sure there isn't something in your data pipeline that precludes the possibility of `quote.Estimator` ever evaluating to `null` or `String.Empty`, because your Linq statement is saying that it is never evaluating to one of those two values.

Comment: No, what I'm attempting to accomplish is to find if it DOES evaluate to either `null` or `String.Empty`. If it does, I would like `Estimator` to be assigned the value of `"Unassigned"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and see if you're receiving the same values:

```
Estimator = ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(quote.EstimatorID) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(quote.EstimatorID.Trim())
? (db.Employees.Single(c => c.EmployeeID == quote.EstimatorID)).FullName 
: "Unassigned")
```

If that doesn't work, try replacing the check in the ternary expression (!string.IsNullOrEmpty part) with false and see if you reach "Unassigned".  I've found that sometimes, when you use a ternary expression in a LINQ query, you have to wrap the whole thing in parentheses.

Comment: Added a check against a trimmed EstimatorID.  I've had single space values create a debugging nightmare in ADO.NET. I believe LINQ to SQL and EF automatically trim, but I wouldn't rely on that.

Comment: I tried adding yours in, however I received an extremely cryptic error on DataBind when the query was ran.

When I put in false however, it ran just fine.

Comment: That's very weird.  I did have one too many opening parentheses and modified my answer around the time you posted.  It sounds to me like the Single isn't returning what you'd expect.  Maybe change that to `db.Employees.Select(c => c.EmployeeID == quote.EstimatorID).SingleOrDefault()` ?? Is this an option?

Answer (score 1):

I think your expression is correct, although I would advise changing it to `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(quote.EstimatorID)` for clarity.

Note however that your expression could still return null if `db.Employees.Single(c => c.EmployeeID == quote.EstimatorID).FullName` returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Then it looks like `quote.EstimatorID` is not null or empty string. Is db.Employees.Single() returning null here? Debug it - put breakpoints into those parts of the expression (putting them on separate lines, if necessary). If you can't do that wrap methods around them that call Debug.WriteLine() or similar.